# What is the difference between Calendar and Google Calendar in Account sync settings

Tags: calendar, android-10, motorola, google-calendar, google-pixel

In `Settings > Accounts > Select Google Account > Account sync`. There are switches for synchronizing various content of the account, such as `Contacts`, `Drive`, etc. I also have `Calendar` and `Google Calendar` in there. What is the difference, why is there two?

Phone models:
Google Pixel 5
Motorola Moto G8

Comment: It is a Motorola Moto G8 and it has no OEM calendar app that I can find.

Comment: As per [this](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/MOTO-G-MOTO-G-4G-LTE-1st-Gen/Duplicate-calendar-notifications/m-p/3008105?page=2#3008119) Moto ships with it's own calendar app. Can you recheck in your apps// Uninstall Google calendar and see if you can find calendar app

Comment: Thanks, I have rechecked the app drawer. I have gone into `Settings > Apps & notifications > See all 71 apps` and manually scrolled through them all to see if there is any preinstalled calendar app which I might have disabled in the past. I couldn't find any. The app for calendar from Google is simply called *Calendar*. I only have 1 Google account added in the phone at the moment.

Comment: Same question. Samsung Galaxy Tab S6 lite, Android 11. These are clearly two different services from Google Workspace. Disabling Google Calendar sync from settings makes itself visible in both the Calendar app and Outlook. Disabling Calendar sync does not appear to affect anything, from what I can see.

Answer (score 0):

Same question here. Getting an old Samsung Ace 3 out of the drawer, rooted and "upgraded" to LineageOS 14.1 / Android 7.1.2.
`Settings / Accounts / Google` account shows `Calendar` and `Google calendar`, both with switches.
As far as I know, this is not related to any other calendar app that may be installed on the phone, since this settings allow to sync different google services/functionalities.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/246827)